# Pyautogui - Need to hold shift and click

Tags: python, pyautogui

How does one hold shift and and click with the mouse using pyautogui?

```
    pyautogui.hotkey('shift', click(1611, 600))
```

have tried the line above. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 12):

The `hotkey()` function only works with keys. To shift-click, you need code like this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: I JUST REALISED THAT THE GUY WHO WROTE AUTOMATE THE BORING STUFF ANSWERED MY QUESTION!!!!

Comment: Something really weird happened to me. I copied the code. It worked like twice then it stopped working for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: try with `
`pyautogui.keyDown('shift')`
`pyautogui.mouseDown()`
`pyautogui.keyUp('shift')`
`pyautogui.mouseUp()`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution above but for some reason keyDown('shift') didnt work. I used the solution in this thread: [keyDown function not working with shift key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949628/keydown-function-not-working-with-shift-key)

```
pyautogui.keyDown('shiftleft')
pyautogui.keyDown('shiftright')
pyautogui.hotkey('right','right','ctrl','up')
pyautogui.keyUp('shiftleft')
pyautogui.keyUp('shiftright')
```