# How to simulate a mouse click while holding the SHIFT key in Windows?

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse, pyautogui, pynput

Hello I'm trying to simulate a mouse click while holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. I have been trying to do this with the `pynput` module.

This is my code so far:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as Cont
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()
keyboard = Cont()

with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
    mouse.position = (1892, 838)
    mouse.click(Button.left)
```

I know the code for holding the shift key is working (If I try to press the 
"a" button in the code I see an "A"). Also I know the mouse click is working. However, together it does not work.

---

Also I tried another code from a StackOverflow post: [Pyautogui - Need to hold shift and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321602/pyautogui-need-to-hold-shift-and-click)

I tried the following code from it:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

This worked for a minute then it stopped working! Very strange. It fails like 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: Try `mouse.press(Button.left)` and then `mouse.release(Button.left)`. Just a guess though, based on how Windows events usually work.

Comment: Already tried that. It did not work. Thanks for thinking with me though!

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes

Comment: It works then it does not work. It works like once in a very while.

Comment: Hmm, seems to work for me. How do you test it?

Comment: @finefoot i followed your advice and put a time.sleep(10) between the two lines. It did not fix the problem

Comment: @CristiFati I run my python scripts on  sublime text 3. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @finefoot i am going to look in to that. I have a feeling you might be right

Comment: @finefoot you were right. The target was the problem. Somehow it only works if I click on the target before starting to use the shift + click. I did not think that was needed. But it seems to be that case. If you make an answer I will accept it. I feel like you deserve that since you helped solving my problem!

Comment: The question is lacking in detail it seems, because it is working on everyone else's environments. It works 100% on my environment as well, is it due to the focus was not on whatever the target you have and that app/browser whatever does not recognize the click without a focus on it? If so can you elaborate the target window?

Comment: Can you please select the correct answer as the solution? You might confuse future people looking for a similar issue... The current accepted one again wouldn't work without a focus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a timer to it most likely will work.

```
import pyautogui
import time

#cordinates
cordinates = 100,100
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
time.sleep(0.15)
pyautogui.click(cordinates)
time.sleep(0.15)
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Answer (score 0):

The script works as intended, but it seems the *target* on which you are trying to apply <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Click</kbd> is not accepting such inputs while its window on Windows GUI is not in focus. That is why it works when you include a <kbd>Left-Click</kbd> before the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Click</kbd>, because that first click puts the target window (whatever program/app it is) in focus, then the already working but ignored <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Click</kbd> is also accepted by the *target*

Answer (score -1):

Well a workaround i suggest is creating an event listener like this :

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

enter code hereCollect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: OP wants to send input, not receive it.

Comment: Well in my humble opinion the problem with op's code is that he doesn't "spot" the triger event in order to enter the loop and send the click , hope i made myself clear now.