# How i can do event "Click button on screen (in another application, like minecraft)" [py]

Tags: python

How i can do event "Click button on screen (in another application, like minecraft)"
I want make a python thing what clicking buttons on minecraft like:
**'A', 'B', 'C', 'CTRL', 'SHIFT', '1', '2', '3', '\', 'ENTER'** etc.
It will click only 1 time
To find people with hacks, i don't love people who cheating >:d\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a mouse click while holding the SHIFT key in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469486/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-while-holding-the-shift-key-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keyboard module (python) to control keyboard

**first we need install a module name- keyboard in python**

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

**First, let's import the module:**

```
import keyboard
```

**Next, you can also simulate key presses using the send() function:**

it will press space:

```
keyboard.send("space")
```

**This will press and release the space button. In fact, there is an equivalent function press_and_release() that does the same thing.**

---

**You can also pass multi-keys:**

```
keyboard.send("windows+d")
```

**The + operator means we press both buttons in the same time, you can also use multi-step hotkeys:**

send ALT+F4 in the same time, and then send space,

```
keyboard.send("alt+F4, space")
```

**But what if you want to press a specific key but you don't want to release it ? Well, press() and release() functions comes into play:**

press CTRL button

```
keyboard.press("ctrl")
```

release the CTRL button

```
keyboard.release("ctrl")
```

**So this will press CTRL button and then release it, you can do anything in between, such as sleeping for few seconds, etc.**

---

**But now what if you want to write a long text and not just specific buttons ? send() would be inefficient. Luckily for us, write() function does exactly that, it sends artificial keyboard events to the OS simulating the typing of a given text, let's try it out:**

```
keyboard.write("Python Programming is always fun!", delay=0.1)
```

Setting delay to 0.1 indicates 0.1 seconds to wait between keypresses, this will look fancy like in hacking movies!

### THANKS!