# Shift and mouse click

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse, keyboard-events, pyautogui

I am trying to hold shift key and at the same time click with the mouse. I searched the internet and found a stackoverflow question about this. This is the post: [Pyautogui - Need to hold shift and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321602/pyautogui-need-to-hold-shift-and-click)

Also the code in this post was working for like three times!

Then suddenly it stopped working. It is really strange. I also tried it with `pynput`. Here is my post: [Holding shift key + mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469486/holding-shift-key-mouse-click/56473371#56473371)

It seems like holding shift and clicking the mouse are working seperately.

However, together it seems not to work

This is the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

I am running on windows OS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a mouse click while holding the SHIFT key in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469486/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-while-holding-the-shift-key-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks working fine?
Maybe use more `keydown('shift')` will make it

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you not to use `pyautogui`.
Its easy and simple with other modules. Install [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)(for controlling keyboard) and [`mouse`](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/)(for controlling mouse)

Here is a sample code that does what you want:

```
import keyboard, mouse       #< Importing the required modules
keyboard.press("shift")      #< Presses and holds the key
mouse.click("left")          #< Makes Left click
keyboard.release("shift")    #< Releases the held key
```